# theming in iphone application

Tags: ios

I am making an ios application for some insurance company, what i want to achieve is that, i want to make the application in such a way that if in future some other company wish to buy my application, i can change the theme accordingly, with out changing the code...

Can you please help ??

Regards
Nakul Kundra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More iOS apps are inherently theme agnostic, in the sense that all functionality that takes advantages of images (UIImageView backgrounds, custom UIButton states, etc.) load the image from a given file name. As such, simply by changing the image files and re-building you can already customise things to quite a large extent. (This applies whether or not the images are set up within Interface Builder or programatically.)

As such, you should already have a large degree of customisation capability simply by changing any custom images you're using for UITableViewCell backgrounds, custom views, etc.

However, you could take this further and load any custom colo(u)rs used from a plist, etc. if this is really the direction you want to go in.

Comment: I appreciate your help,
How can i load custom colors from an xib file ? 
can i apply css on the xib or plist

Answer (score 1):

I gave a fairly comprehensive step-by-step for theming iOS apps here: [How to create Multiple Themes/Skins for iphone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919334/how-to-create-multiple-themes-skins-for-iphone-apps)