# How to create Multiple Themes/Skins for iphone apps?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, themes

I have an iphone app ready and approved by the app store. Now I want to create different themes for my app. Can someone please help me out, with info/links/steps on how to create themes for my app?

I want to create a Metal theme for the Boys and a Pink theme for the Girls. Again by theme I mean, the whole app(features and functionality) is gonna stay the same, but depending on who the user is(boy or girl), he/she can choose the theme they wish to see. And when the theme changes, only the images/Background/music will change according to the applied theme.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by themes? What do you want to "theme" ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant themes like in Windows themes!

Comment: This question should not have been closed, it is a perfectly legitimate question with an interesting set of possible technical solutions, and most people understand the meaning of "theme" in the context of an app.

Comment: Im sorry if i could not be more clear, but what i meant to ask was this: I want to create a Metal theme for the Boys and a Pink theme for the Girls. Again by theme I mean, the whole app(features and functionality) is gonna stay the same, but depending on who the user is(boy or girl), he/she can choose the theme they wish to see. And when the theme changes, only the images/Background/music will change  according to the applied theme. Thank You!

Comment: You should edit your original question to include this information. Then it may be reopened.

Comment: Thank You, I have updated the question. I thought that it would be understood what I meant by "Theme". I did not know that so many people would have difficulty understanding what i mean. Neways, thanx a lot!

Comment: You may need to look at this library. It supports multiple themes/skins on the fly. Supports images and colors currently. Font support will be added in future.

https://github.com/charithnidarsha/MultiThemeManager

Answer (score 132, accepted):

This is quite difficult as apps don't have the equivalent of a css stylesheet.

First you need to work out what parts of the app you want to skin, and when you want to allow the user to swap skins.

I'm going to assume that you want to change images and font colours, and that it's okay if the user has to relaunch the app to change the skin (that will make things simpler for now).

Create a plist containing all your skinnable images and colours. The plist will be a dictionary with sensible, theme neutral key names for the images and colours (e.g. don't have a colour called "red", call it "primaryHeadingColor"). Images will be file names, and colours can be hex strings, e.g. FF0000 for red.

You'll have one plist for each theme.

Create a new class called ThemeManager and make it a singleton by adding the following method:

```
+ (ThemeManager *)sharedManager
{
    static ThemeManager *sharedManager = nil;
    if (sharedManager == nil)
    {
        sharedManager = [[ThemeManager alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedManager;
}
```

The ThemeManager class will have an NSDictionary property called "styles", and in the init method you will load the theme into your styles dictionary like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *themeName = [defaults objectForKey:@"theme"] ?: @"default";

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:themeName ofType:@"plist"];
        self.styles = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    }
    return self;
}
```

(Note: some people don't like doing a lot of work inside an init method. I've never found it to be an issue, but if you prefer, create a separate method to load the themes dictionary and call it from your app's setup code).

Notice how I'm getting the name for the theme plist from user defaults. That means the user can select a theme in your preferences and save it and the app will load that theme next time it is launched. I've put in a default theme name of "default" if no theme is selected, so make sure you have a default.plist theme file (or change the @"default" in the code to whatever your default theme plist is actually called).

Now that you've loaded your theme you need to use it; I'm assuming your app has various images and text labels. If you're loading and laying those out in code then this part is easy. If you are doing it in nibs then it's a bit trickier but I'll explain how to handle that later.

Now normally you would load an image by saying:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

But if you want that image to be themable, you'll now need to load it by saying

```
NSDictionary *styles = [ThemeManager sharedManager].styles;
NSString *imageName = [styles objectForKey:@"myImageKey"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

That will look in your theme file for the themed image that matches the key "myImageKey" and will load it. Depending on which theme file you've loaded you'll get a different style.

You'll be using those three lines a lot so you may want to wrap them up in a function. A great idea would be to create a category on UIImage that declares a method called something like:

```
+ (UIImage *)themeImageNamed:(NSString *)key;
```

Then to use it you can just replace any calls to [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]; with [UIImage themeImageNamed:@"foo"]; where foo is now the theme key instead of the actual image name.

Okay, so that's it for theming your images. To theme your label colours, suppose you're currently setting your label colours by saying:

```
 someLabel.color = [UIColor redColor];
```

You would now replace that with:

```
NSDictionary *styles = [ThemeManager sharedManager].styles;
NSString *labelColor = [styles objectForKey:@"myLabelColor"];
someLabel.color = [UIColor colorWithHexString:labelColor];
```

Now you may have noticed that UIColor doesn't have a method "colorWithHexString:" - you'll have to add that using a category. You can Google for "UIColor with hex string" solutions to find code to do that, or I've written a handy category that does that and a bit more here: https://github.com/nicklockwood/ColorUtils

If you've been paying attention you'll also be thinking that instead of writing those three lines over and over, why not add a method to UIColor called:

```
+ (UIColor *)themeColorNamed:(NSString *)key;
```

Just like we did with UIImage? Great idea!

So that's it. Now you can theme any image or label in your app. You could use the same trick to set the font name, or any number of other potentially themable visual properties.

There's just one tiny thing we've forgotten...

If you've built most of your views as nibs (and I see no reason why you wouldn't) then these techniques aren't going to work because your image names and font colours are buried inside impenetrable nib data and aren't being set in your source code.

There are a few approaches to solve this:

1) You could make duplicate themed copies of your nibs and then put the nib names in your theme plist and load them from your theme manager. That's not too bad, just implement the nibName method of your view controllers like this:

```
- (NSString *)nibName
{
    NSDictionary *styles = [ThemeManager sharedManager].styles;
    return [styles objectForKey:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
}
```

Notice my neat trick of using the class name of the view controller as the key - that will save you some typing because you can just make a base ThemeViewController with that method and have all your themable view controllers inherit from it.

This approach does mean maintaining multiple copies of each nib though, which is a maintenance nightmare if you need to change any screens later.

2) You could make IBOutlets for all of the imageViews and labels in your nibs, then set their images and colors in code in your viewDidLoad method. That's probably the most cumbersome approach, but at least you don't have duplicate nibs to maintain (this is essentially the same problem as localising nibs btw, and pretty much the same solution options).

3) You could create a custom subclass of UILabel called ThemeLabel that automatically sets the font color using the code above when the label is instantiated, then use those ThemeLabels in your nib files instead of regular UILabels by setting the class of the label to ThemeLabel in Interface Builder. Unfortunately if you have more than one font or font colour, you'll need to create a different UILabel subclass for each different style.

Or you could be devious and use something like the view tag or accessibilityLabel property as the style dictionary key so that you can have a single ThemeLabel class and set the accessibility label in Interface Builder to select the style.

The same trick could work for ImageViews - create a UIImageView subclass called ThemeImageView that, in the awakeFromNib method replaces the image with a theme image based on the tag or accessibilityLabel property.

Personally I like option 3 best because it saves on coding. Another advantage of option 3 is that if you wanted to be able to swap themes at runtime, you could implement a mechanism where your theme manager reloads the theme dictionary, then broadcasts an NSNotification to all the ThemeLabels and ThemeImageViews telling them to redraw themselves. That would probably only take about an extra 15 lines of code.

Anyway, there you have a complete iOS app theming solution. You're welcome!

UPDATE:

As of iOS 5, it's now possible to set custom attributes by keyPath in Interface Builder, meaning that it's no longer necessary to create a view subclass for each themable property, or abuse the tag or accessibilityLabel for selecting styles. Just give your UILabel or UIImageView subclass a string property to indicate which theme key it should use from the plist, and then set that value in IB.

UPDATE 2:

As of iOS 6, there is now a limited skinning system built into iOS that allows you to use a property called the *UIAppearance proxy* to skin all instances of a given control class at once (there's a good tutorial about the UIAppearance APIs [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6)). It's worth checking if this is sufficient for your skinning needs, but if not, the solution I outlined above still works well, and can be used instead, or in combination with UIAppearance.

Comment: Does someone have a reference for how one can do this in iOS5+?  Is it still using a plist, and how does one hook that up from the IB?

Comment: @Luke, this isn't an official Apple approach. There are some new theming options available in iOS5, such as using the UIAppearance proxy to set global styles for your views. But the technique I suggested still works perfectly well in iOS5 and 6, and is still the easiest approach for swapping between themes at runtime.

Comment: @NickLockwood, I am wondering whether this is still the best approach to create themeable apps, that are able to swap themes at runtime, for iOS8?
By the way, your answer deserves more upvotes then I can give :)

Comment: @ShumaisUlHaq yes, nothing significant has changed in this area since the addition of user definable runtime attributes in iOS 5, which I already mentioned. More controls support tintColor, etc. now, which is nice, and there is also the UIAppearance proxy, which allows you to set styles on a per-class basis instead of having to configure each control individually, but this approach is still the only true flexible way to skin anything in your app IMHO.

Comment: @ShumaisUlHaq I've added some details about UIAppearance in case that's useful.

Comment: We have integrated theme by subclassing.

Comment: How can we add images with same name for different themes. Xcode warns about duplicate. Isn't it?

Comment: @iphoneGuy I never said to do that. The key param for the themeImageNamed: method would be a key into the styles dictionary that would return the actual image name, which would be different for each theme.

Comment: @NickLockwood I was finding this solution from the first day when i start coding in iOS App, & now 3rd solution is the best one for me... Thanks a lot & +1 for this much proper answer...