# How to update the whole UI according to the configuration the user selects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a `configfile1.plist` file in my app bundle that includes all the required settings for the UI of the app, i.e. the background images, the animations, the sounds, database, and anything else. I have used a ConfigFileManager class in which there's this method as follows:

```
-(void) loadConfigFile
{
    configFile = [[NSBundle  mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ConfigFile1"
                                              ofType:@"plist"];
rootDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:configFile];

//__ settings
settings = [rootDictionary objectForKey:@"settings"];
timerMode = [settings objectForKey:@"timerMode"];
timePerQuestion = [settings objectForKey:@"timePerQuestion"];
if (timerMode.intValue == 1) {
    //__time is fixed.
}
else
{
    //time is not fixed, there's an initialTime to begin with, and it increases if the answer is correct (timePerQuestion), and doesn't change if it's wrong.
    initialTime = [settings objectForKey:@"initialTime"];
}

//__ Textures
textures = [rootDictionary objectForKey:@"textures"];

//__ buttons
buttons = [textures objectForKey:@"buttons"];
buttonBackground = [buttons objectForKey:@"buttonBG"];
buttonBackgroundSelected = [buttons objectForKey:@"buttonBGSelected"];
mainMenuPlayButton = [buttons objectForKey:@"mainMenu.playButton"];
.
.
.
}
```

This is the default configuration for the app for which the method is called in the app delegate while the app is being opened. Now let's say I have `configfile2.plist`, `configfile3.plist`, and so on. I have a `UIViewController` for this, too, that must display the available config files in a table view. What should I do this, so that the user can select one of the config files, and that gets applied to the whole app?

Any detailed response will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not store user's choice, and whenever loadConfigFile is called, load user's choice from what's stored rather than "ConfigFile1"?

Comment: @TonyMkenu Have upvoted the answers, already, shall I do anything else? :-/

Comment: @Neeku You accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark icon.

Comment: @TonyMkenu Thank you for letting me know about this. Had never noticed or knew I should do so. : )

Comment: @PeterWarbo helped you :)

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8919422/1702413

Comment: Yes! Have been reading it, while still being surprised at how he's explained everything so nicely! but to be honest I didn't get how it will be selected/applied upon the user's choice.

Comment: Ah! I see! Thought it was you TonyMkenu. Thanks to @PeterWarbo, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is like this:

1. a .plist stores possible options
2. shows the options to user
3. save the selected options to somewhere
4. refresh UI based on saved options

You have done step 1 and 2. So you have to decide where to store the options for later retrieval.

One option is to use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` to save selected options. You may check out [`InAppSettingsKit`](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) and its sample app to see how the whole thing work.