# Reload colors of all views in the app

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiappearance

I am working of changing theme feature and I need to reload all colors in my app.

My app have tabbar.

So, in my first step I reload all colors which I change with appearance (UINavigationBar, UITabBar, etc) by calling method in which I set their colors.

The next my step is reload all 4 tabs and all opened VCs under them.
Here I use code:

```
 let windows = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows
                for window in windows {
                    for view in window.subviews {
                        view.removeFromSuperview()
                        window.addSubview(view)
                    }
                }
```

And it works for all tabs rather them current (navigation VC, root VC and other pushed VC). How can I reload them?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage theme color by, `UIAppearance` as you mentioned in question,`tintcolor` for `button` and other `views`.

You can refer [Raywenderlich's tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929667/customizable-theme-colour-to-design-application-in-ios) and you can refer [My answer from these post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929667/customizable-theme-colour-to-design-application-in-ios) for different trick to manage theme for whole app. And you can refer accepted answer of that same post that states same thing that i have mentioned above (i.e. tintcolor and appearance).

Comment: this is so annoying, I am looking for way with simple calling one method